# How do I wait for a void function to finish executing before triggering a completable in Android?

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java, observer-pattern, rx-android

I'm very new to RxJava/RxAndroid and I'm very confused with how to achieve this workflow:

- Trigger void function
- Once it completes, provide some sort of callback to start a Completable function.

I tried wrapping my void function in an Observable that emits a , but honestly I've no clue if that's the right thing to do.

```
fun observableFoo(): Observable<Unit> {
        return Observable.create<Unit> { emitter ->
            emitter.onNext( voidFunction() )
        }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    }
```

I have another completeable function inside which I have to subscribe to this Observable as follows:

```
fun onClick(): Completable { 

  observablefoo().subscribe {
      Logger.e("demoApp", "inside subscribe - value = $it") 
  }

  val x = someCompletableFunction()
  return x
}
```

I want to be able to first wait for the subscription to finish and then trigger someCompletableFunction(). Is my approach even correct?

I've been stuck on this problem for a day and would really appreciate some help from anyone. Thank you.

Comment: That isn't going to quite work.  I assume voidFunction is asynchronous in some way?  Because otherwise the right way to do it is to just call the other function immediately after calling voidFunction.  But if it is, then what you're trying would emit on the observable after the function call returns, not after any asynchronous work is finished.  But if it isn't asynchronous, why make it an observable at all?

Comment: you're correct - voidFunction() is asynchronous. 

The someCompletableFunction() is like a trigger to a button and I need to perform voidFunction() in such a way that it waits for it complete and only then start.

Is there a way I can add a callback to my voidFunction's observable? Also is creating an Observable which emits a Unit the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: what would be a good alternative to not using observable here?

Comment: So you couldn't use an observable like this.  You'd need to pass some form of synchronization-  a callback, an observable, a semaphore, something- into voidFunction, because only the asynchronous stuff inside of voidFunction knows when its actually done.  You can use an observable like that, but the onNext function would need to be called by the asynchronous part of voidFunction.

Comment: Please show the implementation of `voidFunction`. You can use `Completable.create()` and compose with `.andThen(anotherCompletable)` to execute two completables one after the other.